# Run Jenkins build only on the parent's node

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

I have a Jenkins master and n nodes. I use NodeLabel Parameter Plugin to set up a build to start a build in parallel on all computers when something is pushed on Git.
I also have a job (a test suite) which is started on each node if the build passes.
I need to setup the second job to start only on the node which has started the parent story. if I use the same plugin and setup the job to run on all the nodes. So each build of the parent job will run the test suite in parallel on all the nodes and at the end I have n^2 child jobs executed instead of n.

Comment: How do you trigger the first job to run over all nodes?

Comment: For the moment yes. Later I intend to select only a group using label expressions.

Comment: Using a plugin where you specify that the build is parameterized and then adding parameter type: Node. There I can select on which nodes to execute it. Also I select "Allow multi node selection for concurrent builds"

Comment: have you tried multijob plugin?